# Concatenate columns containing list values in Spark Dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, concatenation, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe (spark) which has 2 columns each with list values. I want to create a new column which concatenates the 2 columns (as well as the list values inside the column).
For e.g.

Column 1 has a row value - [A,B]

Column 2 has a row value - [C,D]

**"The output should be in a new column i.e. "**

Column 3(newly created column) with row value - [A,B,C,D]

**Note:- 
Column values have values stored in LIST**

Please help me implement this with pyspark.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

we can use an UDF as,

```
 >>> from pyspark.sql import functions as F
 >>> from pyspark.sql.types import *
 >>> udf1 = F.udf(lambda x,y : x+y,ArrayType(StringType()))
 >>> df = df.withColumn('col3',udf1('col1','col2'))
```

Answer (score 0):

as general rule, if you want to join more list columns, I suggest to use `chain` from `itertools`

```
from itertools import chain
concat_list_columns = F.udf(lambda *list_: chain(*list_), ArrayType(StringType()))
```

Because udf are heavy on memory, a better solution would be to use pyspark function concat:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
F.concat(col1, col2, col3)
```